# inner product of characters in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, translation-request

tengo una tarea en un curso de grupos de Lie, en la cual debo demostrar que $(\pi_m,\mathbb{C}_m[x,y])$ son las únicas representaciones irreducibles de dimension finita en $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Donde $\mathbb{C}_m[x,y]$, es el espacio vectorial de los polinomios homogéneos, y $\pi_m(g)$ actúa de la forma $\pi_m(g)f(x,y)=f((x,y)\cdot g)$.

Calcular los caracteres no fue muy complicado, tomando la base $\{p_k: 0\leq k\leq n\}$ con $p_k=x^ky^{n-k}$ pues $\pi_m(\exp(H))p_k=\exp(d\pi_m(H))p_k=\exp(2k-n)p_k$, pero la pregunta es como podría definir un producto interior entre estas matrices; pues no tengo la forma de volumen de $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, para definir la integral $\langle f,g\rangle=\int f(z)\cdot\overline{g(z)}dz$.

Podría alguien por favor traducir la pregunta? Gracias

Comment: Translation:  "I have homework in a course on Lie groups, in which I must show that $(\pi_m,\Bbb{C}_m[x,y])$ are the only irreducible representations of finite dimension in $SL(2,\Bbb{R})$.  Here $\Bbb{C}_m[x,y]$ is the vector space of homogeneous polynomials, and $\pi_m(g)$ acts via $\pi_m(g)f(x,y)=f((x,y)\cdot g)$.  It was not too complicated to calculate the characters, taking the basis $\{p_k:0\le k\le n\}$ with $p_k=x^ky^{n-k}$, since $\pi_m(\exp(H))p_k=\exp(d\pi_m(H))p_k=\exp(2k-n)p_k$, but the question is how one could define an inner product for these matrices."  To be continued.

Comment: Continuation of translation:  "For I don't have the volume form of $SL(2,\Bbb{R})$ to define the integral $\langle f,g\rangle=\int f(z)\cdot\overline{g(z)}\,dz$."

Comment: This forum is an English language one I guess.